# Show how many images are attached to a post/page on compose page

Tags: metabox, query, attachments, media-library

On the front-end, I'm using a [query to show all attachments](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-show-wordpress-post-attachments) attached to the current post. However, on the compose page, there's no way for a user to see how many images are attached without opening up the media gallery.

I would like to add a meta box (or something) to display the current number of attached images – perhaps something like this: http://cl.ly/image/0a2q171v3y2u

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'attached_images_meta' );

function attached_images_meta() {
    $screens = array( 'post', 'page' ); //add more in here as you see fit
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
        add_meta_box(
            'attached_images_meta_box', //this is the id of the box
            'Attached Images', //this is the title
            'attached_images_meta_box', //the callback
            $screen, //the post type
            'side' //the placement
        );
    }
}
function attached_images_meta_box($post){
    $args = array('post_type'=>'attachment','post_parent'=>$post->ID);
    $count = count(get_children($args));
    echo '<a href="#" class="button insert-media add_media" data-editor="content">'.$count.' Images</a>';
}
```

The above will link to the media uploader. I added the link because the screenshot you posted looked like a link. Feel free to remove the link like so:

```
echo $count.' Images';
```

Just pop this in your functions.php, custom plugin, etc.